# using docslist.getFolder

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a working app that saves a document into a user-specified folder in their collection.
This works fine except when they want to save into their root folder.

According to the docs,

```
function testGetRoot() {
  var root = DocsList.getRootFolder();
  var folderName = DocsList.getFolderById(rootid);
  Logger.log("Folder name: " + folderName.getName());
}
```

folderName shows 'Root' as the getName for the root of my collection.

So, seeing that I added 'Root' to the ListBox that is populated by the names of the other folders in my collection.  That of course, was too easy..

```
**var collectionFolder =  DocsList.getFolder(selectedCollection)**;
```

I get a 'cannot find folder Root' error message.

So I can get the Name of the root, but can't seem to get it to be accepted by getFolder method.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not missing anything. You should report this issue in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list), as it makes sense. But as a alternative, which I'd probably use even if this worked, is referencing always to the folder id. e.g.

```js
listbox.addItem(folder.getName(), folder.getId());

//then, later on in your handler...
//you'll receive the selected folder id directly, instead of its name.
//allowing you to use the more reliable getFolderById
var selectedFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(e.paramater.listbox);
//which works also for the root folder
```

Comment: Henrique,  I guess it's either a bug or a lack of documentation :)  Thanks for the reply !

Comment: You understood my alternative (better IMHO) solution though, right? By the way, I see you do not mark most of your as answered (i.e. accept an answer), you should do it if you feel you got a good answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wound up hardcoding 'Root' in the logic where I addtoFolder, so that if the user selects Root, the addToFolder method isn't called. The default behavior is that the document will be saved to the Root collection, unless otherwise specified.